# How to convert a std::array to a std::vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector

I need to convert a `std::array` to a `std::vector`, but I could not find anyway to do it quickly. Here is the sample code:

```
 std::array<char,10> myData={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

Now I need to create a vector such as:

```
std::vector<char> myvector;
```

and initialize it with the array values.

What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: Good question, really, but why is the array typeof `char` and the initializer list uses numbers?

Comment: @RYoda I want to array of data which can behold inside a char, so no reason to define the array of int which consumes more memory.

Comment: @mans Should probably use `int8_t` for that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the [constructor of `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) taking iterators.

> Constructs the container with the contents of the range [first, last).

e.g.

```
std::array<char,10> myData = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
std::vector<char> myvector(myData.begin(), myData.end());
```

Answer (score 7):

Just for variety:

```
std::vector<char> myvector(std::begin(myData), std::end(myData);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
std::vector<char> myvector { myData.begin(), myData.end() };
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the range constructor of vector - looking like `myvector(myData.begin(), myData.end())`

for future reference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector